# php code for determing an mpeg-4 files codecs

Tags: php, h.264, codec

I need to run checks on .mp4 files to check if they have a h.264 codec to create a php condition or at least just to print  the codecs. Is there some fairly simple code that will run in a html file?

Comment: html is a markup language. it has utterly and absolutely **NO** way of doing anything close to what you want.

Answer (score 2):

Using:

- https://code.google.com/p/php-mp4info/

This is their example test file:

```
include "MP4Info.php";

print '<h1>MP4Info test script</h1>';
print '<p><small>'.__FILE__.' $Id: test.php 2 2009-06-11 14:12:31Z lacroix.tommy@gmail.com $</small></p>';
print '<hr />';

$dir = './TestFiles/';
$de = opendir($dir);
if ($de) {
    while (($file = readdir($de)) !== false) {
        $path = $dir.$file;
        if ((!is_file($path)) || (!is_readable($path)) || (strtolower(pathinfo($path,PATHINFO_EXTENSION) != 'f4v'))) continue;

        print '<h2>'.$file.'</h2>';
        print "<pre>";
        try {
            print_r(MP4Info::getInfo($path));
        } catch (MP4Info_Exception $e) {
            print 'Caught MP4Info_Exception with message '.$e->getMessage();
            throw ($e);
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            print 'Cauth Exception with message '.$e->getMessage();
            throw ($e);
        }
        print "</pre>";
        print '<hr/>';
    }
} else {
    print '<strong>Could not open directory "'.$dir.'".';
}
```

It does support finding out if video has h.264 encoding.

Comment: @user1557515, did this answer the question for you?